# Unable to view a file using win32 dir command and Python subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, dir

I'm attempting to read in a file and produce a hash of said file. For the most part, this has gone smoothly. However, there are a few files that I am unable to get a handle to. For instance:

```
file("c:\\windows\\system32\\nvvsvc.exe")
```

Produces the error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\windows\\system32\\nvvsvc.exe`

Similarly, the command:

```
subprocess.check_output(r"dir c:\windows\system32\nvvsvc.exe", shell = True)
```

Produces the error:

> File Not Found
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< stdin >", line 1, in < module >
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
>
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
>
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'dir c:\windows\system32\nvvsvc.exe' returned non-zero exit status 1

I tried many variations thereof, including trying to even get cacls.exe to admit there's a file there. However, when I back out of the python instance (exit()) and perform a `dir c:\windows\system32\nvvsvc.exe`, it returns that there is indeed a file there.

A similar test using calc.exe instead allows me to view it and hash it both just fine from inside python.

I'm running Python 2.7. I've attempted kicking off python with administrative privs (run as administrator for the command prompt), but that doesn't change anything. There appears to be some change in privileges when running from inside python to the extent that the file system is essentially pretending that file doesn't exist to python.

For reference, the owner of the file in question (there are others that are similar), is system, and the cacls on the file allow reading of it from user, admin and system.

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem. Are you running from an [elevated prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Command-Prompt-frequently-asked-questions)?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer! (but not necessarily easy to find) In regards to the IOError, it's because you don't need to escape backslashes.

The second part looks like a permissions error, as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: So I've attempted it with raw formatted strings as well (thus, no double escaping the file name) to the same error.

Also, I have attempted it with and without an elevated command prompt. It does not appear to change things.

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this, but have you looked at the [python docs on subprocesses](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)? They talk about the error and they might spark an idea about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the 64-bit system try this:

```
subprocess.check_output(r"c:\windows\SysNative\nvvsvc.exe", shell = True)
```

The key here is "SysNative"